# Проверить вхождение свойств и значений из одного объекта в другой

Tags: javascript

Есть необходимость проверить наличие пар КЛЮЧ: ЗНАЧЕНИЕ из одного объекта в другом.
Если хоть одно сравнение отсутствует - вернуть false. Если все совпало - вернуть номер.
Пример:

```
 const obj = {
      '0': '1.2294',
      '1': '0.6634',
      '2': '8.1167',
      '3': '0.2936',
      '4': '3.5590',
      '5': '1.7247',
      '6': '6.6207',
      '7': '5.9992',
      '8': '5.5911',
      '9': '5.6656',
      '10': '4.4482',
      '11': '1.0487',
      '12': '7.4847',
      '13': '7.7417',
      '14': '2.9427',
      '15': '0.1428',
      '16': '3.7415',
      '17': '5.6842',
      '18': '1.1759',
      '19': '5.5838',
      '20': '6.5913',
      '21': '6.4061',
      '22': '2.3436',
      '23': '7.7358',
      '24': '7.3307',
      '25': '4.2396',
      '26': '5.4466',
      '27': '9.5938',
      '28': '8.7445',
      '29': '4.5083',
      num: 0
 };


const needToFind = {
  '0': '1.2294',
  '4': '3.5590',
  '12': '4.4222'
};


const objLength = Object.keys(needToFind).length;

for(let i = 0; i < Object.keys(needToFind).length; i++){
  if(obj[Object.keys(needToFind)[i]] !== needToFind[Object.keys(needToFind)[i]]){
    break;
  }
  else{
    console.log(obj.num);
  }
}
```

Нужно проверить, есть ли в объекте obj такие же пары ключ-значение, что и в объекте needToFind.
Пример приведен по циклу, но он работает не правильно.

Comment: * но он работает не правильно.* почему не правильно?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko на примере в объекте needToFind ключ 12 имеет не такое же значение как 12 в объекте obj. Но всеравно я получу свойство num, так как другие пары совпадают.
Пример я написал на скорую руку, чтобы просто показать, что я хочу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать вот так.

```js
const obj = {
  '0': '1.2294',
  '1': '0.6634',
  '2': '8.1167',
  '3': '0.2936',
  '4': '3.5590',
  '5': '1.7247',
  '6': '6.6207',
  '7': '5.9992',
  '8': '5.5911',
  '9': '5.6656',
  '10': '4.4482',
  '11': '1.0487',
  '12': '7.4847',
  '13': '7.7417',
  '14': '2.9427',
  '15': '0.1428',
  '16': '3.7415',
  '17': '5.6842',
  '18': '1.1759',
  '19': '5.5838',
  '20': '6.5913',
  '21': '6.4061',
  '22': '2.3436',
  '23': '7.7358',
  '24': '7.3307',
  '25': '4.2396',
  '26': '5.4466',
  '27': '9.5938',
  '28': '8.7445',
  '29': '4.5083',
  num: 0
};




function findIn(sourceObject, targetObject) {
  return !Object.keys(sourceObject).some(s => sourceObject[s] !== targetObject[s]) ? targetObject.num : false;
}

const needToFind = {
  '0': '1.2294',
  '4': '3.5590',
  '12': '7.4847',
  '29': '4.5081',
};

console.log(findIn(needToFind, obj));

const needToFind2 = {
  '0': '1.2294',
  '4': '3.5590',
  '12': '7.4847',
  '29': '4.5083',
};

console.log(findIn(needToFind2, obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понял тз, но вот так я вижу сравнение объектов. Может даст какую идею.

```js
const obj = {
      '0': '1.2294',
      '1': '0.6634',
      '2': '8.1167',
      '3': '0.2936',
      '4': '3.5590',
      '5': '1.7247',
      '6': '6.6207',
      '7': '5.9992',
      '8': '5.5911',
      '9': '5.6656',
      '10': '4.4482',
      '11': '1.0487',
      '12': '7.4847',
      '13': '7.7417',
      '14': '2.9427',
      '15': '0.1428',
      '16': '3.7415',
      '17': '5.6842',
      '18': '1.1759',
      '19': '5.5838',
      '20': '6.5913',
      '21': '6.4061',
      '22': '2.3436',
      '23': '7.7358',
      '24': '7.3307',
      '25': '4.2396',
      '26': '5.4466',
      '27': '9.5938',
      '28': '8.7445',
      '29': '4.5083',
      num: 0
 };


const needToFind = {
  '0': '1.2294',
  '4': '3.5590',
  '12': '4.4222'
};

for(let prop in needToFind) {
  for(let i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj).length; i++) {
    if(prop === Object.keys(obj)[i] && needToFind[prop] === obj[Object.keys(obj)[i]]) {
      console.log(Object.keys(obj)[i]);
    }
  }
}
```